# Elliptic Cylinder Coordinates Integral

Tags: calculus

Could somebody show me an example of an integral that becomes easy when you change to elliptic cylinder coordinates $x = a\cosh(\eta)\cos(\phi)$, $y = a\sinh(\eta)\sin(\phi)$, $z = z$, or even (&?) an integral where you would think to change your variables to these coordinates? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the integral of the constant function $1$ over an elliptic cylinder, for example $$\displaystyle \int_{x^2+2y^2\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1}dV.$$

Comment: Should that be $0 \leq z \leq 1$? Thanks by the way! Any ideas on when it would function as a convenient change of variables given a more complicated integrand?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I fixed it. For the other part, you can consider the integrand to be for example the inverse of the Jacobian of the change of coordinates. Then, you will integrate the constant function $1$ after changing the coordinates.

Comment: That's a great idea, that is literally a weapon you've just given me, thanks a bunch!